# Mouse over text - image shows on fixed position

Tags: image, text, hover, mouse, mouseover

When someone mouse over a text I want a image to show

example: www.hiphopking.nl

I have no idea what it is called. Does someone know what I should google to get something similar like that?

Comment: I searched 'jQuery hover image link preview' and found http://www.freshdesignweb.com/jquery-mouseover.html. #23.

Comment: do you mean the text (image hover effect jquery css3) that appears when you hover mouse over the first image on the above link ?

Comment: The demo from the above link: http://cssglobe.com/lab/tooltip/03/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to achieve? The task itself could be easily done with a few lines of jQuery, look at this sample I just created for you:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#myText").hover(
      function () {
        $("#myImage").show();
      },
      function () {
        $("#myImage").hide();
      }
    );    
});​
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/umn9F/